# Quantum ideal gas - Canonical ensemble - Occupation number summation notation (Huang)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, quantum-statistics

(Question at the end, in bold, marked with an ***b)***)

For the quantum ideal gas, the hamiltonian (operator) of the system is:

\begin{align}
\mathcal
H=\sum_{i=1}^N H_i=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{P_i^2}{2m}
\end{align}

where $N$ is the number of particles.

In the canonical ensemble we have

\begin{align}
\mathcal
\rho = e^{-\beta \mathcal{H}}
\end{align}

where $\rho$ is the density operator and $\beta = \frac{1}{K_BT}$.

The entry $jj$ of the matrix that represents this operator in the basis of eigenvectors of $\mathcal{H}$ is, then:

\begin{align}
\mathcal 
\rho_{jj} = e^{-\beta E_j}
\end{align}

and thus, the partition function is given by:

\begin{align}
Z_N = Tr[\rho]=\sum_{j=1}^\mathcal{N} e^{-\beta E_j}
\end{align}

where $\mathcal{N}$ is the number of eigenvalues $E_j$ of $\mathcal{H}$ (repeated included).

***a)***

This is what's written in some Statistical Mechanics books/notes (e.g., Huang):
\begin{align}
Z_N = \sum_{\{n_p\}} e^{-\beta E }
\end{align}

with

\begin{align} 
E=\sum_{\vec{p}} \epsilon_\vec{p} n_\vec{p} \quad , \quad N=\sum_{\vec{p}} n_\vec{p}
\end{align}

where $n_\vec{p}$ is the occupation number (number of particles) corresponding to a configuration with momentum $\vec{p}$ (?) and $\epsilon_\vec{p}$ the respective energy.

***b)***

**Is $E_j = E \,$? If so, how can I see that? If not, what exactly does $Z_N$ as written in the books (i.e. the summation as the above) mean?**

Addendum:

- I thought that if the system is in the state $|\Psi^{(j)} \rangle$, eigenvector of $\mathcal{H}$ associated with $E_j$, then maybe $|\Psi^{(j)} \rangle = |\phi_1^{(j)} \rangle |\phi_2^{(j)} \rangle...|\phi_N^{(j)} \rangle $ (with $|\phi_i^{(j)} \rangle$ being the state of particle $i$ when the system is in the state $|\Psi^{(j)} \rangle$) and, thus, 
  \begin{align}
  \mathcal
  H|\Psi^{(j)} \rangle &= \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N H_i \bigg) |\phi_1^{(j)} \rangle |\phi_2^{(j)} \rangle...|\phi_N^{(j)} \rangle \\
  &= \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i^{(j)} \bigg) |\Psi^{(j)} \rangle  
  \end{align}

$\qquad$ with $\epsilon_i^{(j)}$ being the eigenvalue of $H_i$ associated with the eigenvector $|\phi_i^{(j)} \rangle$.

- Since  $\mathcal{H}|\Psi^{(j)} \rangle = E_j |\Psi^{(j)} \rangle$, we would have:

\begin{align}
\tag{*} E_j = \sum_{i} \epsilon_i^{(j)}
\end{align}

- If $n_\vec{p}$ particles have momentum $\vec{p}$, then I guess we could write this as:

\begin{align}
E_j = \sum_{\vec{p}} n_\vec{p}^{(j)} \epsilon_\vec{p}^{(j)} 
\end{align}

- Finally, instead of doing a sum over $j$, they decide to do a sum over all possible $n_\vec{p}$, thus getting the formula in the books. Is this correct?

**EDIT (reply to glance):**

This is what I got:

Suppose $E_1$ and $E_2$ are eigenvalues of the total hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$ with $g_{E_1}=2$ and $g_{E_2}=1$. Then, there are two eigenstates $|E_{1_a} \rangle$ and $|E_{1_b} \rangle$ for which

\begin{align}
\mathcal{H} |E_{1_a} \rangle = E_1|E_{1_a} \rangle \\
\mathcal{H} |E_{1_b} \rangle = E_1|E_{1_b} \rangle 
\end{align}

and one state $|E_{2} \rangle$ for which $\mathcal{H} |E_{2} \rangle = E_2|E_{2} \rangle$.
Each of these states may be written in terms of the states of the particles, $|\epsilon_{i} \rangle$  (eigenstates of $H_i$ with eigenvalues $\epsilon_i$). Say $N=3$ and that, e.g.:

\begin{align}
& |E_{1_a} \rangle = |\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2},\epsilon_{2} \rangle \rightarrow \text{config} \quad \{n_p\}_{1_a}=\{ p_1,p_2,p_2\} \\
& |E_{1_b} \rangle = |\epsilon_{2},\epsilon_{2},\epsilon_{1} \rangle \rightarrow \text{config} \quad \{n_p\}_{1_b}=\{ p_2,p_2,p_1\} \\
& |E_{2} \rangle = |\epsilon_{5},\epsilon_{5},\epsilon_{2} \rangle \rightarrow \text{config} \quad \{n_p\}_2=\{ p_5,p_5,p_2\}
\end{align}

Then, corresponding to $E_1$, we have occupation numbers $n_{p_1}=1$, $n_{p_2}=2$ and $n_{p_k}=0$ $\forall k>2$ and, for $E_2$, occupation numbers $n_{p_2}=1$, $n_{p_5}=2$  and $n_{p_k}=0$ for $k\neq 2,5$.

$Z$ would then be, according to your **(2)**:

\begin{align}
Z &= e^{-\beta (1 \epsilon_1 + 2 \epsilon_2 +  \sum\limits_{k>2} 0 \epsilon_k)} + e^{-\beta (1 \epsilon_1 + 2 \epsilon_2 + \sum\limits_{k>2} 0 \epsilon_k)} + e^{-\beta (1 \epsilon_2 + 2 \epsilon_5 + \sum\limits_{k \neq 2,5} 0 \epsilon_k)} \\
&= 2e^{-\beta (1 \epsilon_1 + 2\epsilon_2)} + e^{-\beta (1\epsilon_2 + 2\epsilon_5)} \\
&= g_{E_1}e^{-\beta E_1} + g_{E_2}e^{-\beta E_2}
\end{align}

Comment: You may find this useful: http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that to get the partition function you have to sum *over all states*, with the usual Boltzmann weight factor $e^{-\beta E}$.

If you label the energy eigenstates of your system with $| n \rangle$ then the partition function will have the form
$$ \tag{1} Z = \sum_n g_n e^{-\beta E_n},$$
where $E_n$ is the energy of the $n$-th state, and $g_n$ is a possibly present degeneracy factor counting the number of states with energy $E_n$ (which in the non-degenerate case is equal to 1 and thus unnecessary).

If you are dealing with a many-particles system one way to label the states is by specifying the configuration $\{ n_j\}_j$, i.e. the occupation number $n_j$ of the $j$-th particle, for every particle $j=1,...,N$, and the partition function can accordingly be written as
$$ \tag{2} Z= \sum_{\{n_j\}} g(\{n_j\}) e^{-\beta E(\{n_j\})}, $$
where it is important to notice that the energy $E$ depends on the configuration $\{n_j\}$.

However, while **(2)** is usually more practical in these circumstances, one could equally well express the partition function in the form **(1)**.
To try to make it clearer I'll show how we would do this:
let $E_j$ denote the eigenenergies *of the total system* (so rembember that this $j$ is different from the one used above, which labeled *one-particle* states). Then the partition function has the form
$$ \tag{3} Z = \sum_j g_j e^{-\beta E_j}.$$
Why is this equal to **(2)**? Because we are still counting all states, just in a different way. Now $g_j$ is the *number of states with total energy $E_j$*, i.e. in terms of how the single-particle states are distributed:
$$ g_j = \sum_{\{n_{\textbf p} \}\, | \sum_{\textbf p} \!\epsilon_{\textbf p}=E_j} g( \{n_{\textbf p} \}),$$
where $\epsilon_{\textbf p}$ is the energy of an electron in the state $\textbf p$, and I am now labeling single particle states using their momenta $\textbf p$.

Comment: I am not sure, the $j$ index you used does not make much sense to me - isn't the occupation number the number of particles occupying a given state?  As far as I could understand, what you wrote suggests that, if I consider **(*)** (assuming the addendum up to this part is correct) I may not only have several particles with the same energy, $\epsilon_i$, corresponding to $E_j$, but there may also be particles with energy $\epsilon_i$ corresponding to another eigenvalue $E_k$. The total number of particles with energy $\epsilon_i$ will then be $n_\vec{p}$ (like in the book), right?

Comment: The index $j$ labels the one particles states, meaning that each particle is in some state which we label $j=1,2,...$.
With $\{n_j\}$ we mean the $N$-particles state with $n_1$ particles in the state $j=1$, $n_2$ particles in the state $j=2$ and so on. The condition
$$ \sum_j n_j = N,$$
where $N$ is the total number of particles is implicit in these calculations (and in the sum **(2)**).
With **(2)** we mean that we can have $n_1$ of the $N$ particles in the state $j=1$, $n_2$ in the state $j=2$ and so on. Each of these states is equally valid, and so we sum over all of them.

Comment: @nvon in the case of free particles you can think of the index $j$ as labeling the momenta, i.e. as being your $\textbf p$. Given that the energy dispersion relation is $E_{\textbf p} = \textbf p^2/2m$ there is a one-to-one corrispondence between the two. So call it $n_j$ or $n_{\textbf p}$, the key point is that you are labeling the single particle states.

Comment: @nvon I edited the post. Tell me if that helps

Comment: I think we were saying the same thing, but the repeated $j$ index got me confused. I edited the post (**EDIT**) by adding an example - is that in agreement to what you wrote?

Comment: @nvon yes I agree with what you wrote (note however that in your examples the particles are not identical, otherwise you should have for example also the state $E_{1_c} = |\epsilon_2,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \rangle$, but that is not relevant to your problem I think).

Comment: I was thinking of identical particles. That means the degeneracy of $E_n$ is determined by the number of ways we can distribute the same $p_i$s momenta among the identical particles (thus resulting in the same configuration). Thanks!